# WordPress get json data single value

Tags: php, json, wordpress

Trying to get the single value from google finances api. I can retrieve the data perfectly however when I try to echo out a single value it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help?

My code is:

```
  $request  = wp_remote_get('http://www.google.com/finance/info?q=NASDAQ%3aGOOG', $args );                  
                $price    = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );

                print_r($price);
```

The output is:

```
    // [
    {
    "id": "304466804484872"
    ,"t" : "GOOG"
    ,"e" : "NASDAQ"
,"l" : "533.75"
,"l_fix" : "533.75"
,"l_cur" : "533.75"
,"s": "2"
,"ltt":"4:01PM EST"
,"lt" : "Dec 2, 4:01PM EST"
,"lt_dts" : "2014-12-02T16:01:56Z"
,"c" : "-0.05"
,"c_fix" : "-0.05"
,"cp" : "-0.01"
,"cp_fix" : "-0.01"
,"ccol" : "chr"
,"pcls_fix" : "533.8"
,"el": "533.00"
,"el_fix": "533.00"
,"el_cur": "533.00"
,"elt" : "Dec 2, 7:59PM EST"
,"ec" : "-0.75"
,"ec_fix" : "-0.75"
,"ecp" : "-0.14"
,"ecp_fix" : "-0.14"
,"eccol" : "chr"
,"div" : ""
,"yld" : ""
}
]
```

I've tried echoing out the single value, adding a foreach statement and then echoing out the value based on 'l_fix' and the 'id', and also tried splitting the string up but it wouldn't work.

Thanks

Comment: have you used json_decode()?

Comment: Because you're rendering JSON, you can also use a plugin that renders json-data in wordpress, e.g. twiganything.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it:

```
 $request  = wp_remote_get('http://www.google.com/finance/info?q=NASDAQ%3aGOOG', $args );                  
 $data = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
 $data = str_replace('//','',$data);
 $data = json_decode($data);
 $price = $data[0]; // $price = array_shift($data);
 print $price->l_fix .....
```

Google APIs (in this specific case) return JSON with two first chars ('//').